# postgresql - getting an ordered array from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

for a table like this

```
id|col
1 |a
2 |b
3 |a
```

I would like to get an array of just col elements ordered by how often they appear in the table. how can this be done?

Comment: Sample output please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT col
             FROM yourTable
             GROUP BY col
             ORDER BY COUNT(*) );
```

Comment: `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` may be